# how to get the current volume size attached to aws ec2 instance through java sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

I have attached EBS volumes to my AWS ec2-instance but to fetch the current size of the AWS ec2 instance utilized I have to ssh and put command `df -hT /dev/xvda1`, and I get the value that 7% is occupied with full details but I want to get this value through my java code so how can I get this ?

I am trying this code, but it always returns me 0.

```
DescribeVolumesRequest volumerequest = new DescribeVolumesRequest();
System.out.println(volumerequest.getFilters().size());
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you

`com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.Volume`, and you should be using `getSize`.

You can find the reference [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/Volume.html#getSize--)

Comment: In my java code i am attaching an ebs volume of 100gb and then i am copying some user data scripts of 7gb and i have turned in a sleep mode for 8 minutes and then i check for the volume still it is saying 100gb but it should show 93 gb or 7 gb also if it will show then it will be good